# How can i put the picture to the foreground?

Tags: android, background

In my app, there's a listview and 2 pictures. Unfortunately, the foreground picture is the one which I meant to be the background. I want to change the priority somehow. Can anybody help please? :)

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/hatter"
tools:context="hu.szada.nagyteszt.SecondActivity"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gratulauzenet"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/gratulalok"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Szintelso"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/egy"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szegytextegy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szegytextketto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Szintmasodik"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/kettozart"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szkettotextegy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szkettotextketto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szkettotextharom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Szintharmadik"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/haromzart"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szharomtextegy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szharomtextketto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Szharomtextharom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

......

Answer (score 0):

you can set only one background to a view. if you want somehow combine two images try to do this in a xml file. And then simply set it as background.

Or in java code try to use Drawable class or GradientDrawable or something else

Finally, on failes there is a lovely canvas for help)

PS there is no listview

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of views in the xml file. If you have several views in the same position the ones declared later in the xml file will overlap the ones declared first. If it doesn't work try changing the order whit the bringToFront() method

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.myView);
v.bringToFront();
```